# Constrain point to surface

Tags: mesh, vertices, constraints

Is there a way to lock a vertex from object1 to the surface of object2? More specifically I am talking about the end of a spline which should be locked to the surface of a mesh (not only a single face of the mesh).

Answer (score 3):

Use a hook modifier on the control point. Fortunately there is a easy helper operator for that.

Select the control point, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> > New Object, then go back into object mode, select the empty, add a "Shrinkwrap" constraint and select the target object.

[image]

Comment: Thaniks. I'll give it a try. But I was hoping that the point stayed on the cube if I tried to transform the point it self, not the cube. So does it work for that as well?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question next time. In that case, I'm afraid it won't. The point will get projected on the mesh, but offset by the difference in location between the original position of the control point when you applied the hook modifier, and its final location.